# does event.wiget.pack_forget() work in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have some code, and simplified it here, but the event will not work, can I please get some help

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def Delete():
    event.wiget.pack_forget()

db = Button(root, text = "delete", command = Delete)
db.pack()
```

the error code is the following

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/idlelib/run.py", line 119, in main
seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/queue.py", line 172, in get
raise Empty
queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
     return self.func(*args)
   File "/home/travis/trying to delete stuff.py", line 4, in Delete
event.wiget.pack_forget()
NameError: name 'event' is not defined
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you run that code? I am guessing you get an error. Please post the full error. It is telling you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Which widget are you trying to `forget`?

Comment: The button, db. the one using the delete function. - CommonSense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that using the `command` parameter of a button does not pass an `event` object to the function it calls. if you want an event you need to try something like:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def Delete(event):
    event.widget.pack_forget()

db = Button(root, text = "delete")
db.bind('<Button-1>', Delete) # using a binding triggers an event
db.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/trying to delete stuff.py", line 7, in <module>
    db.bind('<Button1>', Delete) # using a binding triggers an event
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1099, in bind
    return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1054, in _bind
    self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))
_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "Button1"

Comment: my mistake, i missed a hyphen, will ammend answer. and @CommonSense the predefined behaviour is irrelevent as bindings can be chained (so multiple on the same event) and by adding `return 'break'` the last binding added can prevent the previous bindings from firing

Comment: see this link: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pythondoc-tkinter-widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.bind-method

Comment: @James Kent, i missed your hyphen too, since I never use `<Button-1>`, because `<1>` just a same thing.

Comment: i know, i personally prefer to use `<Button-1>` as it's clearer that its not the keyboard key